# javaScript error : is not a construct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function on index page for calling youtube videos:

```
function yt() {
    var players = [];

    $('.galleryBlock .slider-for .item')
        .each(function() {
            var $obj = $('<div></div>'),
                $this = $(this);

            $this.append($obj);

            var player = new YT.Player($obj[0], {
                height: $this.height(),
                width: $this.width(),
                videoId: $this.data('video'),
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: false,
                    rel: false
                }
            });
            players.push(player);
        })
}
```

When page loading first time (ctrl+f5) function works property, but after, when videos is cached, console log print this error:

> Error! TypeError: YT.Player is not a constructor

And video-slider doesn't work. Can any one help with this problem?

Comment: Please provide the definition of YT.Player

Answer (score 0):

**Reference document:** [YouTube Palyer API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Here you go with a solution

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Then your function

```
function yt() {
var players = [];

$('.galleryBlock .slider-for .item')
    .each(function() {
        var $obj = $('<div></div>'),
            $this = $(this);

        $this.append($obj);

        var player = new YT.Player($obj[0], {
            height: $this.height(),
            width: $this.width(),
            videoId: $this.data('video'),
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: false,
                rel: false
            }
        });
        players.push(player);
    })
}
```

Hopw this will help you.